# Stopping at filesystem boundary (git_discovery_across_filesystem not set) - Was previously initialized git

Tags: git

I had a working git repo and during a rebase, my Windows PC crashed and after restarting, all I see is

```
Stopping at filesystem boundary (git_discovery_across_filesystem not set)
```

Any git command results in `fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /mnt)`

I don't have to `git init` as I already had an initialized repo (i just did it anyway).

Note that I am using /mnt/ path in WSL on Windows

Does anyone what to do? Did I lose all my local git data?

Comment: Are you _sure_ that your CWD is inside the git repo?

Comment: You mentioned that your system crashed. Is anything else missing from your filesystem? Is a fileystem that you expect to be mounted not mounted?

Comment: It is mounted. i can access all the files there in that path fine.

Comment: the contents of my git are just obviously corrupted

Comment: Are you able to find hidden directory `.git` ?

Comment: Yup I can find a `.git` directory in the repo

Answer (score 0):

##### short answer

It seems that you were working on a special volume (partition or external device) that hasn't been remounted after your PC crash. Go back to `/home`, then try to to mount it back before trying again.

##### long answer

This message indicates that you're not currently in a Git repository when running the command.

To know where it is, Git actually checks the content of the current working directory for a subdirectory named `.git`, that is supposed to be located at top of your repository. If this subdirectory cannot be found, Git will assume you're currently in one of the subdirectories of your repository, and will consequently go up into the parent directory. And it will do as many times as necessary.

However, it will still need eventually to stop. Git will actually stop looking for it either if it reaches the root directory `/` (nothing above by definition) **or** if it reaches the top directory of a mounted volume (assuming the initialization of a new repository won't propagate across two different volumes, the one being mounted at some point above the other). Thus the message you get.

The message you quoted here states that Git went up to `/mnt`, which means that you were inside this directory, which is the place where special volumes (partition and such) or external storage device are usually mounted.

You first need to `cd` elsewhere (your `/home` is a good place for this), then trying to remount the concerned volume, then go back to your former directory and try again. You should retrieve all you data without significant problem.

**Note**: if Git stops at `/mnt`, this can mean that it recognizes this place as being a known pivot point, but it can also see it as a real top directory of some volume. In this latter case, this could mean that something has been mounted on `/mnt` instead of `/mnt/something`, hence masking every previous volumes that could have been mounted here too… and still are even though one can see them.